# Javascript - Get text from html to string

Tags: javascript, php, html

It's a php while with javascript codes. I want that this:

Check every 1 seconds that **chat_status.html** -text's: status = "offline"

Full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// jQuery Document
$(document).ready(function(){

function loadChatStatus(){  
    var status = ("http://tulyita.hu/chat/chat_status.html".text);
    if(status == "offline"){
    //this happens 1#
    } else {
    //this happens 2#
    }
}

setInterval (loadChatStatus, 1);    //Reload file every 1 seconds


});
</script>
```

but it isn't worked. :( Can someone help me?

I need the text from the "chat_status.html".

```
function loadChatStatus(){  
    $.ajax({
        url: "chat_status.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){        
            $("#status").html(html); //Insert status into the #status div               
        },
    });
    if($("#status") == "offline"){
    //this happens #1
    } else {
    //this happens #2
    }
}
```

??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `"http://tulyita.hu/chat/chat_status.html"` is a string that will *never* equal `"offline"`. If you want to *load* that page, you should look into AJAX.

Comment: You are checking the URL itself, not what is given back, when calling this URL. Check jQuery docs for the `ajax` functions.

Comment: I need the text from the "chat_status.html".

Comment: You can only test the status of the page you're on since it's Client Side. You could use an `onoffline` Event but it's not backward compatible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events

Comment: Before fixing your code, do you have the ability to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the server? Or is your code going to be hosted on tulyita.hu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.get()` to load the contents from your server and do something with it in the callback. Example (not tested):

```
$.get('http://tulyita.hu/chat/chat_status.html', function (data) {
  if (data === 'chat = off' {
    // happens when offline
  }
  else {
    // happens when online
  }
}, 'text');
```

Note that the page's current content is `chat = off` and not `offline`. Please check the exact contents of `data` after implementing this in your code.

Also note that your HTML page has to be on tulyita.hu or you have to add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header because of the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't declare the loadChatStatus function in .ready() but outside of it. Leave only the setInterval inside the .ready() function. And 1 second is 1000 ms. setInterval expects ms.

Second, use .load() to get the contents of the url, put it in a (hidden) div,and then check what it is. You cannot just do "string".text , as a string has no .text member.